# How can I rename a git stash?

Tags: git, git-stash

I have a stash with an incorrect name. I would like to fix the name so it's accurate.

**How can I rename a stash?**

Comment: pop it and save it again with a different name?

Comment: Popping and stashing again isn't always an option, because the stash might be based on outdated state and result in conflicts when popping. (The outdated state does not even have to exist anywhere in the history anymore.)

Comment: You might be interested in a slightly different workflow: just create a new branch from the stash entry.  Something like: git branch stash/myNewName stash@{13} creates a new branch that has a head commit of the 13th entry in your stash list.

Comment: @JamesMoore you should add that as an answer! I’ll upvote it.

Answer (score 401, accepted):

Let's assume your stash list looks like this:

```
$ git stash list
stash@{0}: WIP on master: Add some very important feature 
stash@{1}: WIP on master: Fix some silly bug
```

First, you must remove stash entry which you want to rename:

```
$ git stash drop stash@{1}
Dropped stash@{1} (af8fdeee49a03d1b4609f294635e7f0d622e03db)
```

Now just add it again with new message using sha of commit returned after dropping:

```
$ git stash store -m "Very descriptive message" af8fdeee49a03d1b4609f294635e7f0d622e03db
```

And that's it:

```
$ git stash list
stash@{0}: Very descriptive message
stash@{1}: WIP on master: Add some very important feature
```

This solution requires git 1.8.4 or later, and yes, it works with dirty working directory too.

Comment: You meant `git stash store`. Indeed, it's a good improvement which avoids dealing with current changes. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: `git show stash@{0}` still shows the old information afterwards.  How to fix that?  (Please note that the stash then gets a different SHA.)

Comment: It feels better to get the hash with `git show` and start with `git stash store`. Then with `git stash list` you will see the old and the new stash. Finally you can clean-up the old stash with `git stash drop`.

Comment: will git stash drop not lose the changes?

Comment: @ShravyaBoggarapu, no, git doesn't remove commit until `git gc` is run. After `stash drop` you can easily find this normally inaccessible commit using `git fsck | grep commit` command.

Comment: I always get a message `"git stash store" requires one <commit> argument`, even if I do a git stash store before.

I applied the concerned stash and did another `git stash save [label]`, which should be the easiest approach, in my opinion...

Comment: @ÐerÆndi simply applying and saving is an easy option, but doesn't work when changes cannot be re-applied due to conflicts. Meanwhile dropping and storing works under any circumstances. I've tested my solution once again - it works just fine on latest git version (2.17.0).

Comment: @JulienCarsique `git stash store -m …` and not just `git stash -m …` because the former can take a commit?

Comment: I said: "Are you insane?" when I read: `git stash drop stash@{1}` But it worked perfectly! Thanks :)

Comment: After doing this, `git stash apply` gives me `fatal: 'refs/stash@{0}' is not a stash-like commit`?

Comment: @hogi storing the renamed copy of the stash before dropping the original is somehow not working for me

had to drop first, save afterwards

Comment: thanks for pointing out `git stash store`! it wasn't listed in the short-help of `git stash -h` so it was harder to find. worth mentioning that you _do_ need to drop first before storing the new one, as otherwise it doesn't show up for whatever reason

Comment: I suggest `git stash push -m "message"` as the [current doc 2.38.1 for git stash store](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-store) say:  _Store a given stash created via git stash create (which is a dangling merge commit) in the stash ref, updating the stash reflog. This is intended to be useful for scripts._

Comment: @PositiveNavid you can also use the short version `git stash drop 1`

Comment: Note for those who run on Powershell may need to run this command : 

```git stash drop stash`@`{0`}```

Answer (score 80):

Unless you do it manually or contribute an improvement to Git, you can use an alias:

```
git config --global alias.stash-rename '!_() { rev=$(git rev-parse $1) && git stash drop $1 || exit 1 ; git diff-index --quiet HEAD; s=$?; [ $s != 0 ] && git stash save "tmp stash from stash-rename"; git stash apply $rev && shift && git stash save "$@" && [ $s != 0 ] && git stash pop stash@{1}; }; _'
```

Usage: "`git stash-rename <stash> [save options] [<message>]`"

With `[save options]` any option of `git stash save`: `[-p|--patch] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-q|--quiet] [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all]`

Example:

```
$ git stash list
stash@{0}: On master: Pep8 format
stash@{1}: On master: co other than master with local changes
stash@{2}: On master: tests with deployAtEnd

# Let's say I want to rename the stash@{2} adding an issue reference:
$ git stash-rename stash@{2} NXP-13971-deployAtEnd

$ git stash list
stash@{0}: On master: NXP-13971-deployAtEnd
stash@{1}: On master: Pep8 format
stash@{2}: On master: co other than master with local changes
```

That will work even if you have local unstaged changes :)

### EDIT 2016/02/22

Simplified script, credits to *qzb*, https://stackoverflow.com/a/35549615/515973

```
git config --global alias.stash-rename '!_() { rev=$(git rev-parse $1) && git stash drop $1 || exit 1 ; git stash store -m "$2" $rev; }; _'
```

Usage: "`git stash-rename <stash> [<message>]`"

Comment: Awesome! Even cooler if you could do `git stash-rename 'tests with deployAtEnd' 'NXP-13971-deployAtEnd'`

Comment: @mikemaccana Easy with grep+awk. I'll update the answer in a few hours.

Comment: This one is the better answer. +1 from me.

Comment: so the answer is 1) clean working copy, 2) apply stash you want to rename, 3) drop it from stash list, 4) create a new stash with the correct message.

Comment: To clarify, you are renaming the last stash, and after such action it becomes the top stash?

Comment: I delete the stash to rename, save current changes if any, recreate the deleted stash with the wanted name, reapply current changes if any.

Comment: Is this method 100% safe?

Comment: @dani-h I think so since Git stores patches for a while until GC and I save the current changes if any.

Comment: I actually stumbled across an issue in the case that the "stash apply" step experiences a merge conflict.  Now, one of the other stashes has gotten renamed to the temp name.  But the rest of the steps after the "stash apply" seemed to work OK when I executed them one at a time manually.

Comment: @dani-h No. because git version < 1.8.4 does not have `git stash store` (for example, default on centos 7) and you will lose stash, "nice"!

Comment: @catpnosis First version (before edit) does not use the store command.

Comment: second version should stop if no parameters are given; instead, it drops then first stash then exits...

Comment: thanks @mikemaccana; it's one-lined because that's the usage for Git aliases. Actually, I just tried in multi-line and it does not register properly in `~/.gitconfig`

Comment: @JulienCarsique is it possible to use an external file?

Comment: This version checks to make sure both arguments are there so it doesn't just drop your last stash accidentally. It also only requires the stash number, not the whole `stash@{0}` reference. https://gist.github.com/jdforsythe/f248bf6c72fc020225cc3e315a32e922  `git config --global alias.stash-rename '!_() { if [ -z \"$1\" ] || [ -z \"$2\" ]; then echo \"git stash-rename 0 NewName\" && echo \"\" && git stash list && exit 1; else stash=\"stash@{$1}\"; rev=$(git rev-parse \"${stash}\"); git stash drop \"${stash}\" || exit 1; git stash store -m \"$2\" \"$rev\" || exit 1; git stash list; fi }; _'`

Comment: Not sure if this is just a zsh problem, but anyone else getting? `fatal: ambiguous argument 'stash@0': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'`

Comment: Be careful with this version of the script (shown in the answer): `git config --global alias.stash-rename '!_() { rev=$(git rev-parse $1) && git stash drop $1 || exit 1 ; git stash store -m "$2" $rev; }; _'`.  If it's called without arguments, it drops the stash at "refs/stash@{0}".  It can be recovered with a command like `git stash store -m 'descriptive message' hash…here`, where the hash is the one shown when git dropped the stash.

Comment: The alias by @jdforsythe in the [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931026/how-can-i-rename-a-git-stash#comment97031938_25935360) only worked for me when I removed the escaping from all of the double quotes (i.e., `\"` → `"`).  I'm using bash, FWIW.

Answer (score 15):

It's very simple. First, undo the last stash with:

```
git stash pop
```

After this, yo can save the stash with a customized name in this way:

```
git stash save "your explanatory name"
```

I hope it useful for you. :)

Comment: The renamed stash may not be the most recent.

Comment: Thumbs up since this more straightforward (ONLY) for the most recent stash .

Comment: If it's not the most recent stash, simply do `git stash apply {N}`, you can find `{N}` via `git stash list`. And then you can remove the old stash with `git stash drop {N+1}`, because the index will get bumped once you stash the changes with a new name.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67017993/2803743

Answer (score 6):

For the benefit of the reader, here is an [extension to the currently accepted and correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35549615/).

If you not only want to correct the stash message and also want to correct the commit message of the stash, such that

```
git stash list
```

and

```
git log --oneline -1 stash
```

both agree to what is shown, you need a bit more. There might be a better way to do it, but this recipe here is easy to understand, I hope.

To be able to do `git commit --amend` you need to be on the TIP of a branch.  Hence the solution is:

```
git checkout -b scratch stash@{1}
git stash drop stash@{1}
git commit --amend -m "$MESSAGE"
git stash store -m "$MESSAGE" HEAD
git checkout master
git branch -D scratch
```

Explained:

- Create a new (not yet existing) "scratch" branch from the "stash in question" and switch to it
- Remove the old stash.  This is safe, as we still have this on the branch.
- Use `git commit --amend` to replace the commit message, this changing the SHA of the "stash in question"
- Store the stash, based on the [qzb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35549615/)
- Switch back (which assumes you came from "master") and cleanup

Drawbacks:

- This switches branches temporarily.  So this recipe can only be applied when `git status --porcelain` is clean (read: does not output anything)
- It renumbers the stashes, so the changed stash becomes `stash@{0}`
- You need to enter the `$MESSAGE` twice or use some environment variable (in the example: `MESSAGE`)
- You need to find an unused branch name

There are ways to do this without switching branches, but this is beyond the scope of this answer.

## Example

```
git init scratch
cd scratch
for a in A B C D; do date >$a; git add $a; git commit -m $a; done
for a in X Y; do echo $a > Z; git stash save --all; done
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all; git stash list
```

Output

```
*-.   e0e281b (refs/stash) WIP on master: 8bdcc32 D
|\ \  
| | * 4d62f52 untracked files on master: 8bdcc32 D
| * 096f158 index on master: 8bdcc32 D
|/  
* 8bdcc32 (HEAD, master) D
* c84c659 C
* 49bb2da B
* b1852c6 A
stash@{0}: WIP on master: 8bdcc32 D
stash@{1}: WIP on master: 8bdcc32 D
```

Now without changing commit (note: the SHA in following will be different at your side):

```
git stash drop stash@{1}
git stash store -m ...changed... 2fbf9007dfdfb95ae269a19e13b8b9ca3e24181c
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all; git stash list
```

Output

```
*-.   2fbf900 (refs/stash) WIP on master: 8bdcc32 D
|\ \  
| | * 246dc5c untracked files on master: 8bdcc32 D
| * 80c5ea0 index on master: 8bdcc32 D
|/  
* 8bdcc32 (HEAD, master) D
* c84c659 C
* 49bb2da B
* b1852c6 A
stash@{0}: ...changed...
stash@{1}: WIP on master: 8bdcc32 D
```

As you can see, `stash@{0}` still is shown as `2fbf900 (refs/stash) WIP on master: 8bdcc32 D` in `git log`.  If you look carefully, you will see, that several commits have changed SHA.  This is due to how stashes are handled (parents are included of the SHA, and stashes have their stashes as parent).

Fix that:

```
git checkout -b scratch stash
git stash drop
git commit --amend -m ...changed...
git stash store -m ...changed... HEAD
git checkout master
git branch -D scratch
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all; git stash list
```

Output

```
*-.   4d55186 (refs/stash) ...changed...
|\ \  
| | * 246dc5c untracked files on master: 8bdcc32 D
| * 80c5ea0 index on master: 8bdcc32 D
|/  
* 8bdcc32 (HEAD, master) D
* c84c659 C
* 49bb2da B
* b1852c6 A
stash@{0}: ...changed...
stash@{1}: WIP on master: 8bdcc32 D
```

As you also can see, `refs/stash` has a changed SHA, too.

Comment: Worth mention: this destroys the index that was saved with the original stash, replacing it with a new index that matches the parent commit of the original stash. If one wasn't planning to use the original saved index (or it already matched the parent of the original stash), this is not a problem.

Answer (score 5):

The `git stash store`-method described in [qzb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35549615/438249) only updates the stash message in one of two places, causing many git frontends to still show the old message. It is however possible to create a commit that duplicates everything from the original stash commit but changes its message.

1. Find the hashes for the stash commit's tree and parents:

   ```bash
   $ git show -s --pretty=raw stash@{0}
   commit f2adfc7bbebe852693ad8f6ac889e4923230c872
   tree 8160d88c6e00e90fcfa183e09d2563f3cdfb304b
   parent a013bd8052d3260fbc95608ed69d0b9cfa0c77cb
   parent 5d5eb80dc03bea8ff2bdd38962a1259b7725d169
   author ...
   committer ...

       Test stash
   ```
2. Create a new commit with the same tree and parents but a different message:

   ```bash
   $ git commit-tree 8160d88c6e00e90fcfa183e09d2563f3cdfb304b \
     -p a013bd8052d3260fbc95608ed69d0b9cfa0c77cb \
     -p 5d5eb80dc03bea8ff2bdd38962a1259b7725d169 \
     -m "Renamed stash"
   f2adfc7bbebe852693ad8f6ac889e4923230c872
   ```
3. Store this commit as a new stash

   ```bash
   $ git stash store \
     -m "$(git show -s --format=%B f2adfc7bbebe852693ad8f6ac889e4923230c872)" \
     f2adfc7bbebe852693ad8f6ac889e4923230c872
   ```

The new stash message needs to be supplied to both *git-commit-tree* and *git-stash-store* because git stores it in two places (the commit and logs/refs/stash).

Note that stashes created with `--keep-index` will have 3 parents, so you'll need to supply the third parent to *git-commit-tree* in that case!

Transforming this procedure into a one-liner for use in a git alias is left as an exercise to the reader ;-). Be sure to use only plumbing commands for this (so avoid e.g. *git-show* and *git-log*).

Comment: Given that the asker can change which answer is _accepted_ at any time, perhaps you need to more stable identifier in your first sentence.  Are you referring to [qzb's answer](/a/35549615/4850040)?

Answer (score 5):

**Answering my own question many years later**: this just got announced, so thought I'd add it here.

A number of GUI git clients (eg, [Fork 1.58](https://git-fork.com/releasenoteswin) and newer) now support direct renames of stashes.

[image]

Comment: For those wondering, [Fork employs](https://github.com/fork-dev/Tracker/issues/218#issuecomment-756692030) the approach described in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65627640/438249).

Answer (score 4):

A lot of complex answers here. I would approach it this way:

First let's find the index of your stash:

```
git stash list
```

Now apply it with `git stash apply {N}`, for example

```
git stash apply 2
```

You can now stash the changes with a new message

```
git stash push -m 'My descriptive stash message'
```

And if you'd like to clean up the original stash, remember to bump the index by 1, since the new stash increments all existing indexes (so we're going for `N + 1` here)

```
git stash drop 3
```

Answer (score 4):

There are some simple approaches here, which work in simple cases.  Such as `git stash apply`:

```bash
$ # Stash any pending changes you have, if applicable.
$ git stash -um "temporary stash"
$ # Re-apply the stashed changes whose message you want to change.
$ git stash apply stash@{1}
$ # Now stash again with the message you want.
$ git stash push -um "good message"
$ # Now you can pop your temporary stash and drop your poorly named one.
$ git stash pop
$ git stash drop stash@{1}
```

That's a great, easy technique in simple cases.  But if the stash you want to reword was made some time ago, or on a
different branch, it might not apply cleanly, and that can make this technique a major pain.

Using `git stash store` also seems easy.  Just `git stash store -m "$msg" $ref`, and off you go.  But that doesn't seem
to work with modern versions of git.  Probably because this creates an entry in `.git/logs/refs/stash` containing your
new message, but doesn't modify the message stored in the actual commit at `$ref`, and `git stash list` apparently now
displays the messages stored in the stash commits, as opposed to the ones in the log.

Here's an example.  I wrapped long lines with a `⏎` symbol.

```bash
$ git init
$ touch foo
$ git add foo
$ git commit -m foo foo
[master (root-commit) a839f24] foo
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 foo

$ git stash push -m "bad message"
Saved working directory and index state On master: bad message

$ git stash list
24e1f0a - stash@{0} (4 seconds ago) On master: bad message

$ cat .git/logs/refs/stash
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 24e1f0aa39ede6e3065dd5c7bbb337af5b2a5d91 ⏎
PDaddy <pdaddy@not-my-real-email-address.com> 1655905352 -0400 bad message

$ git stash drop
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (24e1f0aa39ede6e3065dd5c7bbb337af5b2a5d91)

$ git stash store -m "good message?" 24e1f0a
$ git stash list
24e1f0a - stash@{0} (16 seconds ago) On master: bad message
```

*What?  It still has the same bad message.*

```bash
$ cat .git/logs/refs/stash
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 24e1f0aa39ede6e3065dd5c7bbb337af5b2a5d91 ⏎
PDaddy <pdaddy@not-my-real-email-address.com> 1655905366 -0400 good message?
```

*It has the new message there, though.  So why does `stash list` still show the bad message?*

```bash
$ git show stash@{0}
Merge: a839f24 7b91532
Author: PDaddy <pdaddy@not-my-real-email-address.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 22 09:40:27 2022 -0400

    On master: bad message

diff --cc foo
index e69de29,e69de29..d1d375f
--- a/foo
+++ b/foo
@@@ -1,0 -1,0 +1,1 @@@
++Wed Jun 22 09:40:21 AM EDT 2022
```

You can see that the bad message is still part of the metadata of the actual commit, which we didn't modify.  Doing so
requires replacing commit `24e1f0a` with a new commit.  For commits that are reachable from our current branch, we can
do that with `git commit --amend`, if it's the most recent commit, or with an interactive rebase, otherwise.  But
`24e1f0a` is not only not the most recent commit in whatever branch we're using, it's not reachable at all from our
branch.  It forms the head of an independent branch-like tree.  So we wouldn't want to rebase onto it.

But we *can* check it out and then modify it.  It's pretty easy to do so.

```bash
$ # If we have any pending changes, stash them first.
$ git stash -um "temporary stash before rewording another stash commit"
Saved working directory and index state On master: temporary stash...

$ git checkout 24e1f0a
Note: switching to '24e1f0a'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state.
...snip: protracted warning message
HEAD is now at 24e1f0a On master: bad message

$ git commit --amend -m 'On master: good message!'
[detached HEAD 714d9be] On master: good message!
 Date: Wed Jun 22 09:40:27 2022 -0400

$ git switch -
Warning: you are leaving 2 commits behind, not connected to
any of your branches:

  714d9be On master: good message!
  7b91532 index on master: a839f24 foo

If you want to keep them by creating a new branch, this may be a good time
to do so with:

 git branch <new-branch-name> 714d9be

Switched to branch 'master'

$ # If we made a temporary stash earlier, pop it now.
$ git stash pop
blah blah blah
```

*Now* we can use `git store` to put our reworded commit into the stash list.

```bash
$ git stash store -m 'On master: good message!' 714d9be
$ git stash list
714d9be - stash@{0} (2 minutes ago) On master: good message!
24e1f0a - stash@{1} (10 minutes ago) On master: bad message
```

Let's put our minds at ease that we're not losing anything:

```bash
$ git merge-tree @ stash@{0} stash@{1}
$ # No output is good.  But if we're still not certain...
$ diff <(git show stash@{0}) <(git show stash@{1})
1c1
< commit 714d9be27dee44e96ddd3c5a4a43b35cff34a4cc
---
> commit 24e1f0aa39ede6e3065dd5c7bbb337af5b2a5d91
6c6
<     On master: good message!
---
>     On master: bad message
```

Looks like the only differences are the commit hashes (expected) and the commit messages (that's what we wanted).

So now, we should feel comfortable dropping the old stash.

```bash
$ git stash drop stash@{1}
Dropped stash@{1} (24e1f0aa39ede6e3065dd5c7bbb337af5b2a5d91)

$ git stash list
714d9be - stash@{0} (5 minutes ago) On master: good message!
```

Mission accomplished!

---

See also:

- [Tino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/490291/tino)'s answer, which uses [a similar technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42671046), but creates a temporary branch instead of using a detached head
- [Brecht Machiels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438249/brecht-machiels)'s answer, which [uses a plumbing command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65627640) to make the change more directly.  It's harder to
  understand, but it's a faster and more straightforward solution, since it doesn't require stashing any pending
  changes you might have and checking out a different HEAD.

  The one drawback to this method is that because it creates a *new* commit, it changes the date, and thus the stash's
  position in the list and its reflog selector (the renamed stash becomes `stash@{0}`).

Here's a magic one-liner (but broken up to multiple lines for readability) to accomplish Brecht Machiels's method:

```bash
_commit=$(git stash drop ${stash:-0} | sed -Ee 's/Dropped.+\((.+)\)$/\1/') &&
git stash store -m "$msg" $(
    git commit-tree $(
        git show -s --pretty=%T\ %P $_commit |
        sed -Ee 's/ / -p /g'
    ) -m "$msg"
)
```

Note that this depends on the shell word splitting the output of the inner command substitution.

Here's a more readable script.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

message=$1
stash=${2:-0}
commit=$(
    git stash drop $stash 2>/dev/null |
    sed -nEe 's/Dropped.+\((.+)\)$/\1/p'
)

if [[ -z $message || -z $commit ]]; then
    echo >&2 "usage: $(basename "$0") MESSAGE [STASH]"
    exit 1
fi

args=(
    # Suppress diff output.
    --no-patch
    # Get the tree hash and the hashes of all the parents.
    --pretty=%T\ %P
)
refs=$(git show "${args[@]}" $commit)

# Format the refs as arguments to `git commit-tree` by inserting "-p" in front of
# each of the parent hashes and then splitting on spaces to separate arguments.
args=($(sed -Ee 's/ / -p /g' <<< "$refs"))

# Create a new commit with the same tree and parents as the old stash, but with
# the new message.
new_commit=$(git commit-tree "${args[@]}" -m "$message")

# Store the new commit in the stash.
git stash store -m "$message" $new_commit
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible to do so. There has been [a proposal for stash renaming](https://git.vger.kernel.narkive.com/TtEqcx5U/proposal-for-stash-rename), but it has not been implemented yet.

> My general idea is:
>
> 1. Implement a new `git reflog update` command that updates the message  associated with a specific reflog entry. To do this, a new `update_reflog_ent()` function (in *reflog.c*) would change the message associated with the specific reflog entry to update. An `update_reflog()` function would use `for_each_reflog_ent()` with `update_reflog_ent` to actually do the change.
> 2. A `git stash rename` command would then only need to call `git reflog update` with the appropriate ref and new message.

Or you could, of course, pop the stash and do a `git stash save [message]`

Answer (score 2):

I like figuring out how to do things in git.
But sometimes we can overcomplicate things instead of just keeping it simple and using what we already have.

One simple way to rename a stash in git is:

1. Find the stash you want to rename.
2. Apply the stash to your working area.
3. Stash the changes in your current working area, with the new stash name.
4. Clean up and remove the old stash from your stash list.

---

1. Find the stash you want to rename by getting list of stashes.

```bash
$ git stash list
stash@{0}: On main: Fifth stash
stash@{1}: On main: There will be cake. Rename.
stash@{2}: On main: Third mustache
stash@{3}: On main: Second stash
stash@{4}: On main: git notes
```

2. Apply the stash you want to rename to your working area.

```bash
$ git stash apply 1
```

3. Stash the changes with the new name

```bash
$ git stash -m "The cake was a lie"

$ git stash list
stash@{0}: On main: The cake was a lie
stash@{1}: On main: Fifth stash
stash@{2}: On main: There will be cake. Rename.
stash@{3}: On main: Third mustache
stash@{4}: On main: Second stash
stash@{5}: On main: git notes
```

4. Clean up and remove the old stash

```bash
$ git stash drop 2
Dropped refs/stash@{2}

$ git stash list
stash@{0}: On main: The cake was a lie
stash@{1}: On main: Fifth stash
stash@{2}: On main: Third mustache
stash@{3}: On main: Second stash
stash@{4}: On main: git notes
```

---

**Note**
You can also use `$ git stash pop 1` at step 2 instead of `$ git stash apply 1`.
Using `git stash pop` instead of `git stash apply` will automatically remove the stash from your list of stashes once its successfully applied.
Which means you will not need to do step 4 and remove the old stash from your list of stashes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified version of [Julien's alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25935360/3538165) that lets you properly deal with the `On <branch>` prefix usually prepended to stash names:

```
git config --global alias.stash-rename '!_() { newmsg="$1" && stash=${2:-"stash@{0}"} && newbranch="$3" && sha=$(git rev-parse "$stash") && olddesc="$(git stash list --format=%gs -1 "$stash")" && newdesc="$(if [[ "$newbranch" = "." ]]; then echo "$newmsg"; else if [[ -n "$newbranch" ]]; then echo "On $newbranch: $newmsg"; else if [[ "$olddesc" =~ ":" ]]; then echo "$(echo "$olddesc" | cut -f1 -d":"): $newmsg"; else echo "$newmsg"; fi; fi; fi)" && git stash drop "$stash" > /dev/null || exit 1; git stash store -m "$newdesc" "$sha" && git stash list; }; _'
```

Syntax:

```
git stash-rename <new-name> [<stash> [<new-branch-name> | .]]
```

Example usage:

```
repo[master] % touch tmp && git add tmp && git stash save first
Saved working directory and index state On master: first
HEAD is now at bd62064 Initial commit
repo[master] % touch tmp && git add tmp && git stash save second
Saved working directory and index state On master: second
HEAD is now at bd62064 Initial commit
repo[master] % git stash list
stash@{0}: On master: second
stash@{1}: On master: first
repo[master] % git stash-rename renamed
stash@{0}: On master: renamed
stash@{1}: On master: first
repo[master] % git stash-rename also-renamed stash@{1}
stash@{0}: On master: also-renamed
stash@{1}: On master: renamed
repo[master] % git stash-rename branch-changed stash@{0} new-branch
stash@{0}: On new-branch: branch-changed
stash@{1}: On master: renamed
repo[master] % git stash-rename branch-name-persists
stash@{0}: On new-branch: branch-name-persists
stash@{1}: On master: renamed
repo[master] % git stash-rename no-branch stash@{0} .
stash@{0}: no-branch
stash@{1}: On master: renamed
repo[master] % git stash-rename renamed
stash@{0}: renamed
stash@{1}: On master: renamed
repo[master] % git stash-rename readd-branch stash@{0} develop
stash@{0}: On develop: readd-branch
stash@{1}: On master: renamed
```

Most of the command is for parsing the arguments and figuring out what should be done to the branch name. The `git` tools used are as follows:

- `git rev-parse <stash>` to find the SHA of the stash.
- `git stash list --format=%gs -1 <stash>` to find the *reflog subject* of the stash. Note that this is different from the *commit message* of the stash, which is not changed by this command. The reflog subject is what shows up in `git stash list`, and you can change the reflog subject without changing the hashes of the commits associated with the stashes. However, you can always find the original commit message, so don't use `git stash-rename` to remove sensitive information!
- `git stash drop <stash>` to drop the old *reference* to the stash (but we still have the SHA, so it's not lost).
- `git stash store -m <new-message> <sha>` to save a new *reference* to the stash with the same commit information but a different *reflog subject*.
- `git stash list` to list the stashes after the operation is finished. Note that new stashes are always pushed to the beginning of the list. It would be necessary to re-push *all* the stashes before the stash of interest in order to restore its original position.

Answer (score 1):

For VS Code users who want to operate the stash from UI itself, please use this method:

1. Make sure you have installed [GitLens](https://gitlens.amod.io/) extension.
2. Go to Source Control tab.
3. Check the STASHES section. You will find all your stashes (same like `git stash list`)
4. You will find direct buttons to **Apply Stash**, **Open All Changes**, **Compare with HEAD**, **Rename Stash** and **Delete Stash** respectively for each stash.

[image]

5. To rename a particular stash, click on **Rename Stash** button. Add your desired message and hit enter.

[image]

**NOTE:** This feature came with the updated GitLens extension. Previously there were only three options **Apply Stash**, **Compare with HEAD** and **Delete Stash**.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way: pop your stash with git stash pop then save it again with git stash save your-name

Comment: The renamed stash may not be the most recent.

Comment: @mikemaccana True, but this was still super useful in my case because it was the latest stash, and this means I can skip most of the overly advanced answers here