# How to name a stash in SourceTree if possible?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, git-stash

I am using SourceTree (mac).
I have a few stashed changes.

**How do I give each stash a custom name to better identify what the code is supposed to do?**

Right now when I stash it gets an automatic name in the form
 WIP on [branchname] [last commit message]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide a name for the stash in the dialog box that opens when you create a stash:

- Stage some changed files
- Click the "Stash" button in the toolbar
- The following dialog shows up. Provide a name in the "Message" field.
- The provided "Message" will be used as the name of the stash

[image: Stash Message]

If you are trying to rename an existing stash, it looks like there's no way to currently do this in SourceTree - the only options in SourceTree are to *apply* or to *delete* the selected stash.

Git in general does not provide a built-in way to rename a stash - the consensus seems to be to drop and recreate the stash with a new name. See [how can I rename a git stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931026/how-can-i-rename-a-git-stash) for a question that addresses this in more detail.