# Git: Cherry-Pick to working copy without commit

Tags: git

I have several branches where I keep certain commits that I want to apply to my working copy every now and then. Initially I tried cherry-picking but I do not want to have the commit in the target branch later.

So I did `cherry-pick` + `reset HEAD~1 --soft`

Is there something simpler like cherry-picking to working copy only?

Comment: You have the '-n' flag which means "no commit".  See here: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Comment: For a range of commits `git cherry-pick HEAD..<AwesomeBranch> -n`

Answer (score 676, accepted):

Use '-n' flag with the cherry-picking which is "no commit"

See here: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

```
git cherry-pick -n <HASH>
```

To then unstage the staged changes

```
git reset
```

Comment: `-n` brings the commit to staged area. In order to unstage it `git reset HEAD` would be neccessary.

Comment: Just `git reset` is enough.

Comment: For future readers, who need after this one to pick only certain parts of the commit: use 'git add -p' to select the chunks you need

Answer (score 27):

If you are using Terminal

```
git cherry-pick -n <HASH>
```

If you are using Intellij Idea

```
Settings -> Version Control -> git
untick commit automatically on cherry-pick
```

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4404012212882-Setting-Commit-automatically-on-cherry-pick-disappeared-in-2021-2-Beta-2

Answer (score 21):

You can also use `apply` instead of `cherry-pick` if you're just trying to apply all the changes you made in a commit to your working directory:

```
git show <commit> | git apply
```

This will apply the changes made in  but will **not** add them to staging or create a commit.

Comment: The (dis)advantage of this is that it will not handle conflicts.

Comment: **This helped me.** Because of the way `git stash pop` pops everything into staging (even though I had separate changes in staging and working), I made a fake stash using a throwaway branch with two commits (staging and working). After checking out my main branch, returning the staging commit to staging area was easy with `git cherry-pick --no-commit <staging hash>` but returning the working commit to the work-tree correctly wouldn't have been easy without this trick: `git show <working hash> | git apply`.

Answer (score 16):

### For IntelliJ users

Settings > Version Control > Git: Uncheck **Commit automatically on cherry-pick**

[image]

**Update**

This feature was removed and set to true by default.
There are many complains and maybe they will return it back.

Meanwhile you can achieve the same result with **"Cherry-Pick Selected Changes"** from commit view (as mentioned in the thread shared by Neo):

[image]

Comment: This feature is not available as of  IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.1 (CE).

Comment: Yes, unfortunately :/

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4404012212882-Setting-Commit-automatically-on-cherry-pick-disappeared-in-2021-2-Beta-2

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-275207/Commit-automatically-on-cherry-pick-settings-is-no-longer-available-in-PhpStorm-20212

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you! Sorry that I can't ask a precise question to match this answer.

Answer (score 10):

Simply run:

```
$ git cherry-pick --no-commit <HASH>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was getting errors that `error: server/metadata/metadata-preui-prod.xml: No such file or directory`

So now I do this

`git checkout SHA -- server/metadata && git reset -- server/met 
adata`

### Old

`git show SHA -- file1.txt file2.txt | git apply -`

or all files from SHA

`git show SHA | git apply -`

[How to git-cherry-pick only changes to certain files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717026/how-to-git-cherry-pick-only-changes-to-certain-files/29788254#29788254)

Answer (score 1):

To solve this in Visual Studio 2019 without opening a console I went to the "Git Repository" window and right clicked on the Git Commit history and did a cherry pick on the commit I wanted. This commits the cherry pick. But then I did a right click on the commit below and did a "Reset -> Keep changes (--mixed)" which reset the commit but kept the changes uncommitted.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Janspeed's answer the same works in Visual Studio 2022.
With the target branch selected as working copy, go to Git-> Manage Branches, select desired commit from source branch and right click. Click on Cherry Pick and that will perform cherry pick WITH commit.
Then select working copy branch, and previous commit, on that right click, then clik on Reset ->Keep changes (mixed).
After that on the Git Changes view you will find all changes included in cherry-picked commit under "Changes" (not staged yet), so you can check if every change is what you expect or change it before deciding to commit.