# Programmatically get number of stashes in git

Tags: git, shell, git-stash

My "oldest" stash in a project is something I need to re-apply from time to time. (Yes, there's a reason for this, and yes, it's terrible, but fixing the underlying issue would be more time-consuming than just using `git stash` for now.)

However, the oldest stash has the highest number in the list, so I can't apply it without first using `git stash list` to see what number it is.

Is there some way to make Git print the number of stashes it's currently holding, so that something like this would always print the last stash (in a shell supporting this kind of command-interpolation)?

```
git stash apply $(git stash <count-command>)
```

I realize I can use something like this:

```
 git stash list | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}' | grep -oP '\d+'
```

...but that's pretty hideous, so I'd like to know if there's something simpler.

Comment: You could just define a short alias for your "hideous" working solution, no?

Comment: may be `git stash list |awk -F[{}] 'END{print $2}'`

Comment: Any reason why you're not using a branch with a single commit, that you could cherry-pick?

Comment: @cody Yes, but I would rather have something I can easily remember in case I'm working somewhere without my `.bashrc` setup.

Comment: @alfunx No; that may be a better idea than abusing the stash-list. Thanks!

Comment: @alfunx I don't see any way to apply a commit from a branch without creating a new commit (or possibly just fast-forwarding). I don't want that.

Comment: @KyleStrand There is a flag called `--no-commit` (or shorter `-n`) for the `cherry-pick` command.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given a small sample repository with this stashes:

```
> git stash list
stash@{0}: WIP on foo/master: d9184b5 ...
stash@{1}: WIP on foo/master: d9184b5 ...
```

this gives you the *number* of stash entries:

```
> git rev-list --walk-reflogs --count refs/stash
2
```

But you have to substract `1` to get the last entry :-( Thanks to @alfunx that can be done without shell arithmetic:

```
> git rev-list --walk-reflogs --count --skip 1 refs/stash
1
```

But to get the oldest stash ref directly you can use this:

```
> git log --walk-reflogs --pretty="%gd" refs/stash | tail -1
stash@{1}
```

This works in your case, because `git stash apply` supports both a plain number and `stash@{$NUMBER}` as an identifier for a stash.

Comment: You could `--skip 1` to have one subtracted from the count.

Comment: @alfunx Excellent! Thanks!

Comment: This answers the asker's question, but worth noting `git rev-list --walk-reflogs --count refs/stash` raises an error when there are no stashes.

Answer (score 7):

The given solutions are over-complicated.

A simple solution is just to count the number of lines given by `git stash list`

```
$ git stash list | wc -l
     65
```

Comment: Except that it doesn't work in Windows, whereas all the other solutions are cross platform. 

Comment: The accepted answer pipes to `tail`. That doesn't work in Windows. The original poster mentions using tail, awk, and grep, so they're not using Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Since your stash is just a single commit, you do not strictly speaking need to use a stash mechanism. Once you know the SHA of your stash once, you can either cherry-pick it every time by SHA, or add a tag to it so you can cherry-pick it by label.

When cherry-picking, use the `-n` or `--no-commit` flag.

Comment: I forgot about tagging commits without introducing new branches. Thanks!

Comment: I think my post is the answer to the actual question but this post solves the actual problem :-)

Comment: @A.H. Agreed. +1 regardless

Comment: I'm actually not sure this is ideal, because I _don't_ want to include the changes as a new commit on my working branch; I want to be able to push my commits _without_ including the changes.

Comment: @Kyle You can always soft reset the cherry picked commit

Comment: @Kyle. Updated answer with https://stackoverflow.com/q/32333383/2988730