# Is it possible to create a branch from a stash using the stash name?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-stash

I know

```
git stash branch branchname
```

creates a new branch using the most recent stash

and

```
git stash branch branchname stash@{index}
```

creates a new branch using a stash at a given index. But, is it possible to do something like this?

```
git stash branch branchname stashname
```

Note: This didn't work

```
git stash branch branchname stash^{/name}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stashname"? The stash names *are* `stash@{<number>}`.

Comment: @torek A stash can be saved with a name, or more accurately, a message "git stash save "guacamole sauce WIP" and then applied using that message "git stash apply stash^{/guacamo}" as discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269256/how-to-name-and-retrieve-a-stash-by-name-in-git.

Comment: Ah. That's technically a *message*, not a name. It just goes into the commit message for the work-tree. Unfortunately, the answer to which you linked is also completely wrong. (See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51775672/1256452) to that same question, which appears to be correct.)

Comment: That's why I included, "or more accurately, a message" comment :) In common usage, I'd heard stashes with messages referred to as "named stashes", with the understanding that under the covers, they are stashes with an associated message. Good point about that incorrect answer. So, if we can apply a stash by using the index position can we also do so by message?

Comment: You can certainly do a search (using `git log -g --grep`) and use that to get the stash index or hash ID. You'll need the index, with the `stash@{number}` spelling, for operations that want to also *drop* the stash: the hash ID alone won't suffice here. Since `git stash branch` drops the stash, it needs the index. Very recent Git versions accept a raw number, e.g., `2` means `stash@{2}`, but for older Git compatibility, you might want to stick with the `stash@{...}` syntax for some time.

Comment: I found a helpful comment in the other answer. I'm going to create an alias and use "git log -g stash --grep="message" --pretty=format:"%gd" Thanks @torek!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183911/discussion-between-adriang-and-torek).

Answer (score 0):

git stash branch branchname stash^{/name}
Or
git stash branch  stash@{1}

This command should works. The error from the duplication of branch name "already exist". Try to use new branch name and it will work.