# Name existing git stash

Tags: git

How do I name an existing git stash?

I have 3 different stashes all with different files, but with the same name.

```
stash@{0}: WIP on feat/stripe: fd8fdf8 Merge branch 'master' into feat/stripe
stash@{1}: WIP on feat/stripe: fd8fdf8 Merge branch 'master' into feat/stripe
stash@{2}: WIP on feat/stripe: fd8fdf8 Merge branch 'master' into feat/stripe
```

I tried

```
   git stash push -m "stash name"
```

however, I do not see how to associate it with the stash. I also get the following error.

> No local changes to save

I reviewed this: [How to name and retrieve a stash by name in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269256/how-to-name-and-retrieve-a-stash-by-name-in-git)

However, it does not seem to address what I need to do, or I don't understand it.

Comment: Technically these are not stash *names*, they're just *messages* embedded in the commits and the stash reflog. I'd recommend using `git stash branch` to turn each of these stashes into actual branches, which do have actual names. I generally recommend *not* using `git stash` except for very-temporary purposes.