# git - limit characters in result of git grep

Tags: git

Searching for a pattern across commits containing minified javascript results in one line of context per match. Unfortunately that one line is several pages long, since it is minified javascript and not neatly broken by line breaks.

How can the context of results of `git grep` be limited not just by *lines* of context, but by *total characters* displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

If those minified javascript results are in a specific folder of your repository, you could use [pathspec syntax](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec) to exclude said folder from your [`git grep` output](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep#_examples).

> ```
> git grep solution -- :^Documentation
> ```
>
> Looks for solution, excluding files in Documentation.
>
> After a path matches any non-exclude pathspec, it will be run through all exclude pathspecs (magic signature: `!` or its synonym `^`).
> If it matches, the path is ignored.

Comment: For limiting the number of results, Git 2.38 (Q3 2022) offers now [`git grep -m`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73028239/6309)